# trying to add a field based on conditionals with NifI

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm new to Apache NiFi and currently using it to route message data to various locations.  I'm looking to add some fields based on a set of conditionals.

Currently I have a GetFile Processor that reads log files ---> ExtractGrok that applies a grok pattern to parse ---> ConvertRecord to convert from Grok to Json.  The next part is where I'm stumped/not sure what to do next.

In my json I have a field `refresh_time`  I need to create 2 new fields based on some conditions about the field `refresh_time`

something along the lines of `if refresh_time < 10 then cache = 1; else if refresh_time > 10 then reprocess = 1`

The end goal here is numeric fields `cache` and `refresh_time` that can be used down the road in aggregations.

What would be the best way to add 2 numerical fields based on a condition. Is there a processor for adding additional fields or updating the record to include new fields?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple ways you could achieve what you want to.

**One option** (More readable)

A [QueryRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.QueryRecord/index.html) would let you write a SQL statement across your Records and let you split them by the result. E.g.

Add a dynamic property called `cache` with a value `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE refresh_time < 10`.

Add a dynamic property called `refresh` with a value `SELECT * FROM FLOWFILE WHERE refresh_time > 10`.

The QueryRecord will now have the relationships `failure`, `original`, `cache` and `refresh`.

Branching off from `cache` and `refresh` will be one [UpdateRecord](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.UpdateRecord/index.html) each, with `Replacement Value Strategy` set to `Literal Value`.

For the `cache` relationship, you can add a new dynamic property called `cache` with a value `1`. For the `refresh` relationship, you can add a new dynamic property called `refresh` with a value `1`.

**Similar option** (Possibly more performant)

If you want to avoid the additional UpdateRecord, you can add fields in the QueryRecord with something like this:

Two dynamic properties set as:

`cache` = `SELECT *, 1 AS cache FROM FLOWFILE WHERE REFRESH < 10`

`reprocess` = `SELECT *, 1 AS reprocess FROM FLOWFILE WHERE REFRESH > 10`

This option may be more performant due to fewer disk reads.

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/sdairs/828e5b9095782613c7da04e065e67109) is an example of the second option, you can [import it to NiFi](https://alasdairb.com/2021/08/22/importing-individual-flow-definitions-in-nifi/) to try it out.

Also, FYI there is a [GrokReader](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.14.0/org.apache.nifi.grok.GrokReader/index.html) that you could use in ConvertRecord to parse with Grok straight to JSON, potentially skipping the ExtractGrok.

Comment: The QueryRecord Processor option was the best choice for my application.  Thanks again.